# Group identical sibling tags in HTML code using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I'm looking for a way to group unnecessary identical inline sibling tags in HTML using Javascript.

For example, turning this:
`<b>Hel</b><b>lo</b><b> World</b>`

Into this:
`<b>Hello World</b>`

It should work for all tags containing all kinds of attributes (class, style, etc.)

A more complex example, turning this:
`<b><span class="test">Hel</span></b><b><span class="test">lo</span></b><b> World</b>`

Into this:
`<b><span class="test">Hello</span> World</b>`

Answer (score 0):

For your example string, this would work. Note, I added a space in between an instance of `</b>  <b>` to show the reason for the `(\s*)` in the regex

```js
let str = '<b>Hel</b><b>lo</b>  <b> World</b>';
str = str.replace(/<\/b>(\s*)<b>/g,'')
console.log(str)
```

Comment: It should work for all tags containing all kinds of attributes, so a simple regex isn’t enough. I’m updating my question.

Comment: so you want to just discard any classes or styles on the internal tags? Please clarify your question by using an example that represents what you're talking about with expected result. thx.

Comment: I didn't mention discarding clases or styles. I'm sorry if my example wasn't clear enough. I edited it.